# Datagrid ComboBoxColumn for Enums is empty on application start and Items.Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I've spent a full day's worth of time Googling for help and haven't found much success with this issue. I've trying to bind an enum to a ComboBoxColumn in a Datagrid, and had a fair bit of success. My only issue now is, upon the application starting or using `Items.Refresh()`, is that all ComboBox columns are empty. Newly added rows also have empty ComboBox fields.

The ComboBoxes currently functions as intended and can set values, but the fields are still empty upon startup. Of course this is not desirable behavior. The best result I've gotten so far trying to remedy the issue is having only the New row column show a default field (in this case "None"), which is also not desired. I do not remember how to reproduce that.

I do not know if the issue is specific to Enums or not, but it's being used for the ComboBoxes, so I'm considering it as related.

Example code

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ProfileData"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Player}"
    Margin="0,150,0,0"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name"
                            Binding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="Name"
                            Width="150"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Race"
                                x:Name="RaceComboBox"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{x:Null}"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Race}"
                                TextBinding="{x:Null}"
                                Width="150">
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

//
// Extra stuff to display ProfileData content, not necessary for reproduction
//

<TextBlock x:Name="DBText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,25,0,0" Padding="10,10"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Information about the list"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18"/>
<Button x:Name="DisplayDBContentButton" Content="Display DB content" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" Click="DisplayDBContentButton_Click"/>
<Button x:Name="Refresh" Content="Items.Refresh()" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="151,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
    Click="Refresh_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Player> PlayerCollection { get; set; } // List of Players
    ObservableCollection<string> RaceCollection { get; set; } // Races as a string

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Player>()
        {
                new Player() {Name = "Samuel", Race = Race.Human },
                new Player() {Name = "Scoof", Race = Race.Orc },
                new Player() {Name = "Sel", Race = Race.Elf }
        };
        RaceCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        string[] raceList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Race));
        foreach (string s in raceList)
            RaceCollection.Add(s);
        RaceComboBox.ItemsSource = RaceCollection;

        ProfileData.ItemsSource = PlayerCollection;
    }

    //
    // Extra code to display PlayerCollection content, not necessary for reproduction
    //

    private void DisplayDBContentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var displayString = "";
        foreach (Player p in PlayerCollection)
            displayString += String.Format("Name: {0} Race: {1}\n", p.Name, p.Race);
        DBText.Text = displayString;
    }
    private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProfileData.Items.Refresh();
    }
}

//
// Required code again
//

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Default Name";
    public Race Race { get; set; } = Race.None;
}
public enum Race
{
    None,
    Human,
    Orc,
    Elf
}
```

[Link to picture of application on startup and displaying text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6qOr.png)

Of course I'm missing something that's probably obvious, or something's inadvertently screwing something else up, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `ItemSource` of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, in your application, that should be the `RaceCollection`.
But there are some problems in `RaceCollection`:
1. Items in the `RaceCollection` are strings, but `SelectedItemBinding` binds to `Race` type. WPF doesn't know how to cast between `string` and `Race`. So `RaceCollection` should be `ObservableCollection<Race>`.
2. `RaceCollection` is filled by all available values of `Race`, so it can be static.

The Result:
**XAML**

```
<DataGrid
  x:Name="ProfileData"
  ItemsSource="{Binding PlayerCollection}"
  Margin="0,150,0,0"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn
      x:Name="Name"
      Binding="{Binding Name}"
      Header="Name"
      Width="150" />
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn
      Header="Race"
      x:Name="RaceComboBox"
      ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Window2.RaceCollection}"
      SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Race}"
      Width="150">
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Player> PlayerCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Race> RaceCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Race>();
    static Window2()
    {
        var raceList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Race)).Cast<Race>();
        foreach (var race in raceList)
        {
            RaceCollection.Add(race);
        }
    }
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            PlayerCollection.Add(new Player() { Name = "Samuel", Race = Race.Human });
            PlayerCollection.Add(new Player() { Name = "Scoof", Race = Race.Orc });
            PlayerCollection.Add(new Player() { Name = "Sel", Race = Race.Elf });
        };
    }
}
```

It works well in my machine.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V3Vi.png)

Comment: Thank you. Somewhere in my attempts to figure this out a list or OC of type string was used to display the list... or something, so I went with that. This makes far more sense.